# Scroll em div caso seja necessário

Tags: html, div, rolamento

Tenho a seguinte `div` na minha página [html](/questions/tagged/html)

```
<div id="divContent" class='content'>
            Bem vindo ao meu site <br />
            1 index index index index index index index index <br />
            2 index index index index index index index index <br />
            3 index index index index index index index index <br />
            4 index index index index index index index index <br />
            5 index index index index index index index index <br />
            6 index index index index index index index index <br />
            7 index index index index index index index index <br />
            8 index index index index index index index index <br />
            9 index index index index index index index index <br />
            10 index index index index index index index index <br />
            11 index index index index index index index index <br />
            12 index index index index index index index index <br />
            13 index index index index index index index index <br />
            14 index index index index index index index index <br />                                
        </div>
```

Abrindo a **página no navegador do computador**, todo seu **conteúdo** é **exibido**. Porém ao abrir em um **celular** por exemplo, o **conteúdo não cabe** na tela, escondendo as últimas linhas de conteúdo da `DIV`.

Tem alguma maneira de **colocar um *scroll*** só em **caso** de **não caber** o **conteúdo em telas menores**?

Comment: Você diz um scroll horizontal? Poderia adicionar o `css` que já possui?

Comment: usa media query, da uma olhada na minha resposta, vc pode detectar monitores com resolucao menor e aplicar css para mostrar o scroll.

Comment: não funcionou o media query

Comment: Ve esse fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/05f0pxuc/

Comment: Tira esses br's ai e adiciona um <p> coloca o texto com algum alinhamento e defina uma media query para resoluções baixas, se for texto puro nem precisa da media query por que o proprio navegador se encarrega de deixar o texto legível.

Comment: Conseguiu fazer??

Answer (score 14):

Tem como usar o css para mostrar as barras de rolagem.

```
#divContent{
 overflow:auto; 
}
```

Com isso sua div deve ter scroll sempre que precisar.
Existem varias opções para diversos casos.
Veja a definição no site da [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

```
overflow: visible|hidden|scroll|auto|initial|inherit;
```

Para deixar isso apenas para dispositivos mobile, você pode usar MediaQuery, para detectar a resolução e fazer suas alterações.

**Exemplo:**

```
/* mobile phone */
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    #divContent{
     overflow:auto; 
    }
}
```

Esse CSS vai ser aplicado apenas em resoluções até 768px, abrangendo inúmeros devices mobile.
Veja esse [jsFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/05f0pxuc/) com o MediaQuery funcionando.